# Handling Post Request with Servlet by Sending Data to Java DB (Derby)

Tags: java, json, servlets, derby

I am working on an electronic gradebook program that sends an http post request from a Java SE application to a Java EE application.  The Java EE application is running on a GlassFish server.  My goal is for a servlet in the Java EE application to handle the post request by parsing the JSON and sending those values to the Java DB (Derby) database reports table.  In order to make it as simple as possible I am sending, via the post request, one student report at a time containing the following data encoded with JSON: student_id, student_name, instructor_name, school_name, course_name, absent_days, tardy_days, total_grade.  The code below handles the JSON by parsing it.  How can I alter the code below to send the data to the Java DB (Derby) database table?

```
Java Bean

package com.edw.bean;

public class Student {

private String student_id;
private String student_name;
private String instructor_name;
private String school_name;
private String course_name;
private String absent_days;
private String tardy_days;
private String total_grade;

// setters and getters
}

package com.edw.bean;

public class Status {
    private boolean success;
    private String description;

    //setters and getters
}


Servlet

package com.edw.servlet;

import com.edw.bean.Status;
import com.edw.bean.Student;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class JsonParserServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");        
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s;
        while ((s = request.getReader().readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
        }

        Student student = (Student) gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), Student.class);

        Status status = new Status();
        if (student.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("edw")) {
            status.setSuccess(true);
            status.setDescription("success");
        } else {
            status.setSuccess(false);
            status.setDescription("not edw");
        }
        response.getOutputStream().print(gson.toJson(status));
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Status status = new Status();
        status.setSuccess(false);
        status.setDescription(ex.getMessage());
        response.getOutputStream().print(gson.toJson(status));
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
    } 
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
}
```

Comment: Broadly speaking, you'll: open a JDBC connection, prepare an INSERT PreparedStatement, set your particular values into the statement, execute it, and close the connection. Start here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/cgsintro.html

Comment: I appreciate you helping by breaking it down into steps.